# How to Convert a LINQ Query Syntax to a Method Syntax? (with join and multiple selects) Issue: Where-no overloads for + 3 parameters

Tags: linq, syntax

> I am trying to understand lambda expressions with Linq but i struggle with the conversion. Below is the Linq Query syntax which works just fine.

```
var systemUsersPoor =
            (from customer in customers
                join distributor in distributors

                    on new { customer.Location }
                    equals new{ distributor.Location }

                where customer.Location == "UK" &&
                      customer.Location==distributor.Location &&
                      customer.Supplier == "MoneyShits" &&
                      distributor.Products == "ShittyCrappyCraps"

                orderby customer.Name
                select new
                {
                    customerName=customer.Name , customerLocation=customer.Location, customerSupplier=customer.Supplier,
                    distributorName=distributor.Name, distributorProducts=distributor.Products

                }).ToList();
```

> And then in here, i have my failed attempt to convert it into a Linq Method Syntax...All works untill the .Where statement..states that it does have no definition for my fields(.location,.Supplier) and distributor

```
 var sysUserPoor2 = customers.Join       //from customer in customers Join 
        (
            distributors,                        //Join on distributors on customer.Location==distribution.Location
            customer=> customer.Location,        //Select the primary key (the first part of the "on" clause in an sql "join" statement
            distributor =>distributor.Location,  // Select the foreign key (the second part of the "on" clause)

            (customer, distributor) => new      //select statement
            {
                customerName = customer.Name,
                customerLocation = customer.Location,
                customerSupplier = customer.Supplier,
                distributorName = distributor.Name,
                distributorProducts = distributor.Products
            }
        )
            .Where
        (
             customer => (customer.customerLocation == "UK") &&
                         (customer.customerSupplier == "MoneyShits"),
            distributor => distributor.distributorProducts == "ShittyCrappyCraps",
                (customer, distributor) => (customer.customerLocation == distributor.Location)
            );
```

> The query with the code below works, but i dont know how to add the rest somehow...:

```
.Where
        (
            customer => (customer.customerLocation == "UK") &&
                        (customer.customerSupplier == "MoneyShits")
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following.

```
var systemUsersPoor = customers.Join(distributors, 
                customer => customer.Location, 
                distributor => distributor.Location,
                (customer, distributor) => new {customer, distributor})
                 .Where(x => x.customer.Location.Equals("UK") && 
                  x.customer.Location.Equals(x.distributor.Location) &&
                  x.customer.Supplier.Equals("MoneyShits") && 
                  x.distributor.Products.Equals("ShittyCrappyCraps"))
                  .OrderBy(x => x.customer.Name)
                  .Select(x => new
                 {
                    customerName = x.customer.Name,
                    customerLocation = x.customer.Location,
                    customerSupplier = x.customer.Supplier,
                    distributorName = x.distributor.Name,
                    distributorProducts = x.distributor.Products
                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: this works like a charm.. I managed on the previous one to make it with an extra Where statement that adds distributor => distributor.distributorProducts == "ShittyCrappyCraps",
but for the (customer, distributor) => (customer.customerLocation == distributor.Location) iti didnt allow me..due to the parameters conflict...
Thank you very much..i still have a lot more to learn with these lambda's..